# How to only reach a frame when an Image is clicked. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm a newbie at flash pro and I can't fix this little issue...

I have an image on a certain frame, and if you click on it I want go to another frame. If the image is not clicked, then you should not be able to reach that other frame.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

To address some further clarification in the comments:

To prevent the timeline from reaching a frame until an image is clicked, you'll probably want to do the following:

1. Stop the timeline from playing when you reach that image. Do this by putting `stop();` on the frame that contains the image.
2. Listen for the click on the image. Do this also on the frame where the image appears and you put `stop()`.

   ```
   image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, imageClick,false,0,true);
   ```
3. Make your click function, then inside of that (which runs when the image is clicked), go to whichever frame you'd like.

   ```
   function imageClick(e:Event):void {
       gotoAndPlay(5);
   }
   ```

---

There a number of ways to navigate frames in AS3.

The most common, is the `gotoAndPlay` function. This will take you to the specified frame and play the timeline from there.

So if you wanted to go to frame 7 for instance, you would do:

```
gotoAndPlay(7);
```

There is also gotoAndStop, which takes you to the specified frame but stops the playhead there:

```
gotoAndStop(7);
```

For the gotoAndStop/Play methods, you can pass in the frame number, or a frame label in quotes:  `gotoAndStop("myLabel");`

Other things you can do:

```
nextFrame();  //goto the next frame

prevFrame();  //goto the previous frame
```

---

If you are not sure what frame you are on, you find that out with the `currentFrame` property.

So, if you had a script that ran in a timer or enter frame handler, you could do something like this: (if on frame 5, goto frame 1)

```
if(currentFrame == 5){
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Along those lines, there is also the `currentFrameLabel` property, which will tell you what (if any) is the label of the current frame.

There is also `currentLabel`, which will give you the current or (if no label exists on the current frame) the previous label encountered.

Comment: So you're not sure what frame you're on?  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have an image and if you click on it you go to another frame, but I want that if you have not clicked the image you don't reach that frame. @Batman